# nhibernate: save() fails when trying to add record with many-to-one without association object

Tags: c#, nhibernate, many-to-one

Hopefully I'm just missing something obvious. I have a class I want to save a new instance off, definition something like this:

```
<class name="MyClass1" lazy="false" table="table1" dynamic-update="true">
    <id name="id" type="guid" generator="assigned" />
    <property name="class2_id" />

  <many-to-one name="class2" class="MyClass2" not-null="false" lazy="proxy">
    <column name="class2_id" not-null="true" length="40" sql-type="varchar" />
  </many-to-one>
```

```
public class MyClass1
{
    virtual public System.Guid id { get; set; }
    virtual public System.Guid class2_id { get; set; }
    virtual public MyClass2 class2 { get; set; }
}
```

Class2 is set up with the reciprocal Set definition.

I have the id of class2, but don't really want to pull it from the db just to set the reference.

The following works:

```
var class2 = session.Get<MyClass2>(class2_id);
var i = new MyClass1 { class2 = class2 };
session.Save(i);
```

The following fails with "not null property references a null or transient value"

```
var i = new MyClass1 { class2_id = class2_id };
session.Save(i);
```

Is there a correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is use `session.Load<MyClass1>(1)` - that will not hit the database unless you access anything other than the ID.

For further info, check out [Ayende's Blog](http://ayende.com/blog/3988/nhibernate-the-difference-between-get-load-and-querying-by-id) on the topic

Also, I don't think you should map the parent ID in the child class, you should just map the parent object

e.g.

```
public class Child 
{ 
    public Parent Parent { get; set; }
}
```

Rather than

```
public class Child 
{
    public Parent Parent { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; } 
}
```